# opencart 2.2.0.0 on chrome keeps reloading on admin section

Tags: php, opencart

opencart 2.2.0.0 on chrome keeps reloading on admin section

error :

> Navigated to
>   http://loja:82/admin/index.php?route=common/dashboard&token=BnvEv8a6e9h2r2jDeK2osfBs54FEoCDL
>   jquery.js:2 GET
>   chrome-extension://cjabmdjcfcfdmffimndhafhblfmpjdpe/toolbar/styles/placeholder.css
>   net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:2domManip
>   @ jquery.js:2append @ jquery.js:2(anonymous function) @ toolbar.js:1
>   Navigated to
>   http://loja:82/admin/index.php?route=common/dashboard&token=BnvEv8a6e9h2r2jDeK2osfBs54FEoCDL

when i do debug with netbeans i am able to see the message error :

the table orders is empty
i don´t understand where is this

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position
>   842OK{"order":{"label":"Orders","data":[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,0],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0],[13,0],[14,0],[15,0],[16,0],[17,0],[18,0],[19,0],[20,0],[21,0],[22,0],[23,0],[24,0],[25,0],[26,0],[27,0],[28,0],[29,0],[30,0]]},"customer":{"label":"Customers","data":[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,0],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0],[13,0],[14,0],[15,0],[16,0],[17,0],[18,0],[19,0],[20,0],[21,0],[22,0],[23,0],[24,0],[25,0],[26,0],[27,0],[28,0],[29,0],[30,0]]},"xaxis":[["1","01"],["2","02"],["3","03"],["4","04"],["5","05"],["6","06"],["7","07"],["8","08"],["9","09"],["10","10"],["11","11"],["12","12"],["13","13"],["14","14"],["15","15"],["16","16"],["17","17"],["18","18"],["19","19"],["20","20"],["21","21"],["22","22"],["23","23"],["24","24"],["25","25"],["26","26"],["27","27"],["28","28"],["29","29"],["30","30"]]}**Warning**:
>   DB\MySQLi::__destruct(): Property access is not allowed yet in
>   **C:\xampp\htdoc...2****Warning**: DB\MySQLi::__destruct():
>   Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\loja\system\library\db\mysqli.php** on line
>   **62****Warning**: DB\MySQLi::__destruct(): Couldn't fetch
>   mysqli in **C:\xampp\htdocs\loja\system\library\db\mysqli.php** on
>   line **62****Warning**: DB\MySQLi::__destruct(): Property access
>   is not allowed yet in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\loja\system\library\db\mysqli.php** on line
>   **62****Warning**: DB\MySQLi::__destruct(): Couldn't fetch
>   mysqli in **C:\xampp\htdocs\loja\system\library\db\mysqli.php** on
>   line **62****Warning**: DB\MySQLi::__destruct(): Couldn't fetch
>   mysqli in **C:\xampp\htdocs\loja\system\library\db\mysqli.php** on
>   line **62****Warning**: DB\MySQLi::__destruct(): Couldn't fetch
>   mysqli in **C:\xampp\htdocs\loja\system\library\db\mysqli.php** on
>   line **62****Warning**: DB\MySQLi::__destruct(): Couldn't fetch
>   mysqli in **C:\xampp\htdocs\loja\system\library\db\mysqli.php** on
>   line **62**

Comment: Did you set this up in your hosts file? Could it be that you need to flush your DNS cache as not all requests are working.

Comment: yes on the hosts i have 127.0.0.1 loja , i am using xampp on windows 10, the port on xampp is :82

Comment: if i run the opencart with netbeans with chrome on the admin section will reload in loop, outside the netbeans with the chrome firefox ie works fine